# Subclassing MKMapView to provide custom maps?

Tags: ios, maps, mkmapview, mapkit, geospatial

I'd like to provide custom navigation maps in my iOS 6 application. I've tried adding overlay views that shows these custom maps in `MKMapView` and it didn't work well because it needs a higher zoom level than what Apple's component can provide (the desired zoom level is about 10 screen points per meter in the map).

The question is, is subclassing `MKMapView` a good way to approach to this? The primary reason is I'd like to take advantage of `MKMapView`'s coordinate conversion functions:

- `convertCoordinate:toPointToView:`
- `convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:`
- `convertRegion:toRectToView:`
- `convertRect:toRegionFromView:`

Those functions makes it easy to convert screen points to world coordinates (latitude/longitude) and vice-versa.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even though this question is 6 years back: yes, it is better to use the delegate for customizing the MapView.  From Apples documentation about MKMapView: __ Although you should not subclass the MKMapView class itself, you can get information about the map view’s behavior by providing a delegate object. __

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are going to have much luck with subclassing MKMapView. There is a lot going on behind the scenes related to tile loading that you cannot access.

I would guess you would be better served using something along the lines of the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mobile/) or another similar map engine.

It allows you to specify your own tile sources and has plenty of examples to show you how it is done. It also had functions, like map kit, to handle converting values to and from lat/lon.

Comment: iOS 7 allows you to add your own custom tile overlays now.

Comment: Even though this question is 6 years back: yes, it is better to use the delegate for customizing the MapView.  From Apples documentation about MKMapView: